# WordPress query posts by date input type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to display certain posts of a certain date that users can pick via a html date input type.

This is my date input in my html:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" />
</form>
```

And I am trying to get the value like this:

```
$date = $_GET['date'];
echo $date;
```

But I get this error:

> Undefined index: date

Anyone has any idea how I can get the selected date?
I am guessing the form still needs to be submitted, is there any way I can auto submit after selecting a date? Preferably without using JS.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How you will get date parameter by submit button or using jquery

i mean to say how the form is submitted without submit button

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" />
</form>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: use input type text instead of date

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the form's submited or not, example:

```
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
   $date = $_GET['date'];
} else {
   $date = date('d/m/Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to get the value of the date field before you have submitted the form.

Try the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    echo $date;
}
```

You can't make the form submit automatically without using some form of Javascript.

For example:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" onchange="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```